# StringStartsWithKeyMap<T> in Java? (match if key startsWith entry.key)

Tags: java, android, algorithm, tree

I need a `Map` that compares keys with `startsWith()`: keys must match if `key.startsWith(entry.getKey())`. Is there an existing implementation of that?

What I found: a *prefix tree* (a *trie*) is something a bit different, as well as *radix tree* (*compact prefix tree*) and *PATRICIA tree*. I found some implementations, but they do not define methods like `navigableMap.floorEntry(key)` and `navigableMap.higherEntry(key)`.

The tricky part about using `startsWith()` for key comparison is conflict resolution: if the map contains entries for both "foo" and "foobar", what must happen?

It is easy to implement the desired functionality using a `NavigableMap`, e.g. `TreeMap`, if we prohibit conflicting keys, something like:

```
private Map.Entry<String, T> findEntry(String key) {
    Map.Entry<String, T> entry = map.floorEntry(key);
    if (entry != null && key.startsWith(entry.getKey())) {
        return entry;
    }
    return null;
}
```

But if we want to support conflicting keys, we cannot rely on `floorEntry()` like we do in the above code: `map.floorEntry("foobaz")` will find the entry for `"foobar"` rather than `"foo"`. This could be resolved by giving the "foobar" entry a pointer to the "foo" entry... And it looks like we are reinventing the *compact prefix tree* on top of `TreeMap`.

So:

1) Is there an existing implementation of a tree that compares node keys with startWith?

2) Is there an implementation of *compact prefix tree* (*radix tree*) that also `implements NavigableMap` ?

and in the best case, it would be:

3) some analog of `HashMap` supporting a startsWith() match

**UPD**

I have realized that this is a very general problem: *re-classification*.

Given a house address (well, written in the reversal, Country-City-Street-HouseNumber order), find the corresponding post office (zip code).

Given an IP address, find the corresponding provider.

In the general case, the problem is: given an object key, determine the object's class.
The object is identified by a key of M bits, but only first N bits, N<M, define the object's class; N need not be the same for different keys.
The tree nodes need not contain object keys; they contain just enough bits to determine the object's class.

Since the object keys of this sort correspond to some classification (class-subclass-group-subgroup-id), I chose the word *re-classification*.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no default implementation for that, but you can easily write that yourself:

```
    List<String> matchingKeys = map.keySet().stream().
            filter(key -> key.startsWith(prefix)).
            collect(Collectors.toList());
```

When you have matching keys you can adjust what to do. Maybe something like this:

```
    for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if(matchingKeys.indexOf(entry.getKey()) != -1) {
            return entry;
        }
    }
```

Or another approach:

```
Optional<Entry<String, T>> matchingEntry = map.entrySet().stream().
        filter((k) -> k.getKey().startsWith(prefix)).findFirst();

if(matchingEntry.isPresent()) {
    return matchingEntry.get();
}

return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use at the moment. ***It does not support conflicting keys*** (a RuntimeException is thrown when they are detected).

*StringStartsWithKeyMap.java:*

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

/**
 * A map in which a key matches an entry if key.startsWith(entry.key)
 * @param <T>
 */
public class StringStartsWithKeyMap<T> implements Map<String, T> {
    TreeMap<String, T> map = new TreeMap<>();

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return map.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return map.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return null != findEntry((String)key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return map.containsValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public T get(Object key) {
        Entry<String, T> e = findEntry((String) key);
        return e == null ? null : e.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public T put(String key, T value) {
        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            return map.put(key, value);
        } else if (null == findEntry(key) && null == findHigherEntry(key)) {
            return map.put(key, value);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Conflicting keys: \""+key+"\" after "+findEntry(key)+" or before "+findHigherEntry(key));
    }

    @Override
    public T remove(Object key) {
        return map.remove(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends String, ? extends T> m) {
        m.forEach(this::put);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        map.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> keySet() {
        return map.keySet();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<T> values() {
        return map.values();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<String, T>> entrySet() {
        return map.entrySet();
    }

    public StringStartsWithKeyMap<T> putSameValueFor(T value, String... keys) {
        for (String k : keys) {
            put(k, value);
        }
        return this;
    }
    public StringStartsWithKeyMap<T> putSameValueFor(T value, Iterable<String> keys) {
        for (String k : keys) {
            put(k, value);
        }
        return this;
    }
    private Map.Entry<String, T> findEntry(String key) {
        Map.Entry<String, T> entry = map.floorEntry(key);
        if (entry != null && key.startsWith(entry.getKey())) {
            return entry;
        }
        return null;
    }
    private Map.Entry<String, T> findHigherEntry(String key) {
        Map.Entry<String, T> entry = map.higherEntry(key);
        if (entry != null && entry.getKey().startsWith(key)) {
            return entry;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and the tests:

*StringStartsWithKeyMapTest.java:*

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class StringStartsWithKeyMapTest {

    @Test
    public void sizeTest() {
        Map<String, Integer> map3 = makeMap3();
        Map<String, Integer> map0 = makeMap0();
        assertThat(map3.size(), is(3));
        assertThat(map0.size(), is(0));
    }

    @Test
    public void isEmptyTest() {
        Map<String, Integer> map3 = makeMap3();
        Map<String, Integer> map0 = makeMap0();
        assertThat(map3.isEmpty(), is(false));
        assertThat(map0.isEmpty(), is(true));
    }

    @Test
    public void containsKeyTest() {
        Map<String, Integer> map3 = makeMap3();
        Map<String, Integer> map0 = makeMap0();
        assertThat(map3.containsKey("foo"), is(true));
        assertThat(map3.containsKey("foobar"), is(true));
        assertThat(map3.containsKey("quux"), is(false));
        assertThat(map3.containsKey("quuxfoo"), is(false));
        assertThat(map0.containsKey("foo"), is(false));
    }

    @Test
    public void containsValueTest() {
        Map<String, Integer> map3 = makeMap3();
        Map<String, Integer> map0 = makeMap0();
        assertThat(map3.containsValue(1), is(true));
        assertThat(map3.containsValue(1000), is(false));
        assertThat(map0.containsValue(1), is(false));
    }

    @Test
    public void getTest() {
        Map<String, Integer> map3 = makeMap3();
        Map<String, Integer> map0 = makeMap0();
        assertThat(map3.get("foo"), is(1));
        assertThat(map3.get("foobar"), is(1));
        assertThat(map3.get("bar"), is(2));
        assertThat(map3.get("baraboo"), is(2));
        assertThat(map3.get("baz"), is(3));
        assertThat(map3.get("bah"), is((Integer) null));
        assertThat(map0.get("foo"), is((Integer) null));
        assertThat(map0.get(null), is((Integer) null));
    }

    @Test
    public void putTest() {
        Map<String, Integer> map3 = makeMap3();
        map3.put("qux",100);
        assertThat(map3.get("qux"), is(100));
        map3.put("foo",200);
        assertThat(map3.get("foo"), is(200));
        try {
            map3.put("foobar",6);
            assertThat(true, is(false));
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        }
        try {
            map3.put("fo",60);
            assertThat(true, is(false));
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void removeTest() {
        Map<String, Integer> map3 = makeMap3();
        map3.remove("foo");
        map3.remove("baraboo");
        assertThat(map3.size(), is(2));
        assertThat(map3.get("foo"), is((Integer)null));
        assertThat(map3.get("bar"), is(2));
        assertThat(map3.get("baz"), is(3));
        assertThat(map3.get("baraboo"), is(2)); // need exact match for removal
    }

    @Test
    public void putAllTest() {
        Map<String, Integer> map3 = makeMap3();
        Map<String, Integer> map3a = makeMap3a();
        map3.putAll(map3a);
        assertThat(map3a.size(), is(3));
        assertThat(map3.size(), is(5));
        assertThat(map3.get("foo"), is(100));
        assertThat(map3.get("bar"), is(2));
        assertThat(map3.get("baz"), is(3));
        assertThat(map3.get("corge"), is(5));
        assertThat(map3.get("grault"), is(6));
        assertThat(map3.get("corgegrault"), is(5));
    }

    @Test
    public void clearTest() {
        Map<String, Integer> map3 = makeMap3();
        assertThat(map3.get("foo"), is(1));
        assertThat(map3.get("foobar"), is(1));
        map3.clear();
        assertThat(map3.get("foo"), is((Integer) null));
        assertThat(map3.get("foobar"), is((Integer) null));
        assertThat(map3.containsKey("foo"), is(false));
        assertThat(map3.containsValue(1), is(false));
        assertThat(map3.size(), is(0));
    }

    @Test
    public void keySetTest() {
        Map<String, Integer> map3 = makeMap3();
        Map<String, Integer> map0 = makeMap0();
        assertThat(map0.keySet().isEmpty(), is(true));
        assertThat(map0.keySet().contains("foo"), is(false));
        assertThat(map3.keySet().size(), is(3));
        assertThat(map3.keySet().contains("foo"), is(true));
    }

    @Test
    public void valuesTest() {
        Map<String, Integer> map3 = makeMap3();
        Map<String, Integer> map0 = makeMap0();
        assertThat(map0.values().isEmpty(), is(true));
        assertThat(map3.values().size(), is(3));
        assertThat(map3.values().contains(1), is(true));
        assertThat(map3.values().contains(2), is(true));
        assertThat(map3.values().contains(3), is(true));
    }

    @Test
    public void entrySetTest() {
        Map<String, Integer> map3 = makeMap3();
        Map<String, Integer> map0 = makeMap0();
        assertThat(map0.entrySet().isEmpty(), is(true));
        assertThat(map3.entrySet().size(), is(3));
    }

    @Test
    public void putSameValueForTest() {
        StringStartsWithKeyMap<Integer> map3 = makeMap3();
        map3.putSameValueFor(400,"foo","corge","grault");
        assertThat(map3.size(), is(5));
        assertThat(map3.get("foo"), is(400));
        assertThat(map3.get("bar"), is(2));
        assertThat(map3.get("baz"), is(3));
        assertThat(map3.get("corge"), is(400));
        assertThat(map3.get("grault"), is(400));
        assertThat(map3.get("corgegrault"), is(400));
    }

    @Test
    public void putSameValueForTest2() {
        StringStartsWithKeyMap<Integer> map3 = makeMap3();
        map3.putSameValueFor(400, Arrays.asList("foo","corge","grault"));
        assertThat(map3.size(), is(5));
        assertThat(map3.get("foo"), is(400));
        assertThat(map3.get("bar"), is(2));
        assertThat(map3.get("baz"), is(3));
        assertThat(map3.get("corge"), is(400));
        assertThat(map3.get("grault"), is(400));
        assertThat(map3.get("corgegrault"), is(400));
    }

    private StringStartsWithKeyMap<Integer> makeMap3() {
        StringStartsWithKeyMap<Integer> res = new StringStartsWithKeyMap<>();
        res.put("foo",1);
        res.put("bar",2);
        res.put("baz",3);
        return res;
    }

    private StringStartsWithKeyMap<Integer> makeMap0() {
        StringStartsWithKeyMap<Integer> res = new StringStartsWithKeyMap<>();
        return res;
    }
    private StringStartsWithKeyMap<Integer> makeMap3a() {
        StringStartsWithKeyMap<Integer> res = new StringStartsWithKeyMap<>();
        res.put("foo",100);
        res.put("corge",5);
        res.put("grault",6);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have correctly understood your point regarding conflicting keys. If your map contains both foo and foobar as keys and you want to search for 'startsWith(foo)' then in my understanding values corresponding to both foo and foobar should be returned.
In general if you are searching using a prefix of the key, it can never be said with a guarantee that the map will only contain a single key satisfying that prefix.

If you know the data you have stored in the map guarantees that, then you can very well just read the first value returned from the search method.

Search using startsWith can be done as follows:

1. NavigableMap allows you to obtain submap given a fromKey and toKey.
2. Prefix you want to search from is the required fromKey. toKey can be computed from prefix so that we get only those values which satisfy the prefix condition

Example code:

```
public class NavigableMapExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NavigableMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
        map.put("abc", "value0");
        map.put("abcd", "value1");
        map.put("abcdef", "value2");
        map.put("abdfghij", "value3");
        map.put("abcefgh", "value4");
        map.put("abefijk", "value5");

        System.out.println("Values starting from abc");
        // expected output value0, value1, value2, value4

        searchByPrefix(map, "abc").stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static Collection<String> searchByPrefix(NavigableMap<String, String> map, String begin) {
        String end = endKey(begin);
        // map.subMap(fromKey, fromInclusive, toKey, toInclusive), toKey should not be inclusive for our case
        return map.subMap(begin, true, end, false).values();
    }

    public static String endKey(String prefix) {
        return prefix.substring(0, prefix.length() - 1) + (char)(prefix.charAt(prefix.length() -1) + 1);
    }
}
```

Above can also be generalized for non-string keys, provided

1. The universe of keys is sortable (in-fact this is a primary requirement for a NavigableMap, for e.g. TreeMap)
2. The key set supports notion of 'prefix' i.e. prefix(k) < k in sort order
3. We can compute endKey from given prefix p such that

- let set of keys **K** = all keys k in the map where prefix(k) == p
- endKey > k for all keys in **K**
- AND endKey <= k' where k'is the least key > all keys in **K**